# Does there exist a subsequence $n_j$ such that $\int_A f_{n_j}(x)\,dx$ converges for each Borel subset $A$ of $[0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ that is uniformly bounded. Does there exist a subsequence $n_j$ such that 
$$\int_A f_{n_j}(x)\,dx$$ 
converges for each Borel subset $A$ of $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Such that $\int_A f_{n_j} (x) \, dx$ *what*?

Answer (score 3):

Note that your sequence $f_n$ is a bounded sequence in $L^\infty$ and [$L^\infty$ is the dual space of $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405357/when-exactly-is-the-dual-of-l1-isomorphic-to-l-infty-via-the-natural-map), thus the [Banach–Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) implies that there is a subsequence $f_{n_j}$ and $f\in L^\infty$ so that

$$ \int g f_{n_j} dx \to \int gf dx,\ \ \ \forall g\in L^1$$

(Note the identification $(L^1)^* \cong L^\infty$ is given by $L(g) = \int g f dx$). Thus setting $g = \chi_A$, you have

$$\int_A f_{n_j} dx \to  \int_A f dx$$

for all Borel set $A$.